# Show content after X visits using user's IP

Tags: php, cookies, server

I'm trying to show specific content after a user has visited a site for 3 times.
I managed to achieve this with cookies but it doesn't show anymore if surfing with private mode or reseting the browsing session.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(typeof Cookies.get('visited') === "undefined"){
        Cookies.set("visited", 0);
    }
    if (parseInt(Cookies.get('visited')) >= 3) {
          $('.paywall').show();
    } else {
        let increase = parseInt(Cookies.get('visited')) + 1;
        Cookies.set('visited', increase, { expires: 365 });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Is there any resource or does anyone know how I could achieve the same but perhaps by getting the user's IP? This way it will show despite using incognito mode.

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you want it to be between sessions and even between normal and inprivate mode, then you need some authentication and base it on that. IP is a bad identifier since there can be many people using the same public IP (devices behind the same router/vpn/proxy) and one device can get different IP's (dynamically assigned IP's/connecting to different networks etc)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you expand this so I understand better? I'm happy to approach whatever needs to be done. But I have no idea how to face this

Comment: Authentication = they need to have registered an account on your site they can sign in to. Then you will always know who they are.

Comment: The idea is to show a paywall after 4 visits to the site; forcing them to register if they want to keep seeing content. Registration will be a consequence of this paywall showing, but first need to check if a user without account has accessed the site 4 times or more (counting incognito mode)

Comment: You can't make this air tight. If you base it on IP, imagine a company with 1000+ employees, all sitting on the same network. You will only see one single IP no matter who visits the site. So if one person visits it 3 times, all other 1000+ visitors will see the paywall in their first visit. The problem is that you can't identify specific user/device in a reliable way without any authentication. This is by design to protect people's privacy. Even with IP check, you can get around that by connecting to a VPN that assigns random IP's (like many VPN services do)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This makes sense; I understand this better now. So, let's say I managed to simply show the paywall if you don't have an account. What would you recommend doing if I want this non-registered user to have a change to check the site X times before showing it and not using a registering form? Do you think there's a way to accomplish that? Thanks

Comment: I would probably use a different strategy and rather make some content free-for-all while some (premium) content always required an account (you would still list it and let them see an excerpt of it).

Comment: I hope this helps you!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71339918/php-do-something-after-4-requests-from-same-ip/71342353?noredirect=1#comment126108545_71342353